# Analyze SQL Server 2005 Transaction Log using Log Parser

Tags: sql-server-2005, transactionloganalysis

Is it possible to analyze SQL Server 2005 Transaction logs using LogParser 2.2? If not, what is the alternative? Red Gate's tool only analyzes SQL Server 2000 and Lumigent's Log Parser is no where to be found.

TIA
ramesh

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the log is in a proprietary and different format for 2005/2008 and MSFT has not released the specs so there are no log parsers yet that work for 2005 and 2008

Answer (score 0):

If your DB is consuming 75% and your connections are all in use, you might start by checking out the activity monitor and seeing what processes are churning and/or running the profiler before you worry about the log files.

edit:
sorry, initially missed the part where you mentioned you rebooted.

Comment: unfortunately had to reboot so could not attach activity monitor. If no new connections are possible, then I am not sure if profiler can be attached to the server

Answer (score 0):

You would need to attach SQL Profiler to the SQL Instance after the problem has started, but before the SQL Server stops users from connecting. Try pausing the service for a few minutes to allow some of the connections to finish and disconnect then unpause the service and see if profiler can connect.

Also try running SQL Profiler locally on the server.  While remote connections may not work, local connections may.

Answer (score 0):

There is a product that does what I think you are after, unfortunately its not cheap.  It lets you monitor the transaction logs for SQL 2005/2008.  I would love something open source but cant find anything yet.

http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_logapi.asp